# A problem in merged AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android-manifest

I try to build an old android project (2 years old), however I'm stuck on this error.

I got the following error:
Android resource linking failed
Output:  D:\svnserver\crosscyle\crosscycle-android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:51: error: unexpected element  found in .

This is caused by the line:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Apparently this line automatically generated, but at the wrong place.

I also tried to put the the line in the manifest file at the correct place, however the errorness line is still generated.

Below my manifest file (sorry for the mess, it work in progress to having this build):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dynniq.crosscycle">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

      <!--android:name=".base.CrossCycleApp"-->
  <application
      android:name=".base.CrossCycleApp"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_dynniq_app_blue"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".view.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".connectedservice.ConnectedService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"/>
    <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService">
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".view.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SettingsStyle">
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".util.BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".util.GpsLocationReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".util.BatSaveChangeReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.action.ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

And the merged manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dynniq.crosscycle"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.0.7" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" /> <!-- Required by older versions of Google Play services to create GCM registration tokens -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.dynniq.crosscycle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.dynniq.crosscycle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.dynniq.crosscycle.base.CrossCycleApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_dynniq_app_blue"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDvgduUCD3enV0RW1WCpILGc2yeIMxyybs" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.dynniq.crosscycle.view.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.dynniq.crosscycle.connectedservice.ConnectedService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" >
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.dynniq.crosscycle.view.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SettingsStyle" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.dynniq.crosscycle.util.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dynniq.crosscycle.util.GpsLocationReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dynniq.crosscycle.util.BatSaveChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.action.ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaIntentReceiver" />

        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService" />
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.ReconnectionService" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="26.1.0" /> <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsJobService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.PreviewActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppInvite.Preview" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ACTION_PREVIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--
            Service handling Google Sign-In user revocation. For apps that do not integrate with
            Google Sign-In, this service will never be started.
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:permission="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--
             FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerPreviewActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:noHistory="true" > <!-- optional, removes the previewActivity from the activity stack. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="tagmanager.c.com.dynniq.crosscycle" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.dynniq.crosscycle" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--
             FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.dynniq.crosscycle.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION"
            android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help or suggestions are welcome, i'm really stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply solved by creating a new project and copying the source code into the porject. Unknown what the actually the cause of this problem was